# Concat subquery with other columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that returns many columns concated with : ,

```
SELECT DECODE(ship_ps.STATUS, 'A', 'Y', 'N') AS isactive_ship
    ,ship_ps.party_site_id
    ,ship_ps.party_site_number AS site_number
    ,ship_ps.col1 || ship_ps.col 2 
    from ...
    where ....
```

and i have a seprate query

```
(SELECT hp.party_name 
FROM apps.hz_cust_accounts hca,apps.hz_parties hp
WHERE 1=1 
AND hp.party_id=hca.party_id 
AND hca.status='A' 
AND hca.cust_account_id=:p_sold_to_org_id6)
```

i want to concat the result of it with ship_ps.col1 || ship_ps.col 2 || THE_QUERY

How to achieve that

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read an maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Post the full text. You might change the table and column names for confidential purpose. And the sample data. And finally the expected output. Then tell us how you do it. You will get the working code.

Comment: Does this separate query you want to contact returns only one row or multiple ? If multiple how do you then want to concatenate ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run the SQL and got an error?:

```
SQL> select dummy||' '||(select 1 from dual) from dual;

DUMMY||''||(SELECT1FROMDUAL)
------------------------------------------
X 1
```